# Is it possible to get notified when an event subscriber unscribes from the class's event?

Tags: c#, event-handling

Is it possible, when the `Place1` line is executed, to get notified and execute `Place2`?

```
interface ICat
{
    void StartWork();
    public event EventHandler WorkDone;
}
class Cat : ICat
{
    public event EventHandler WorkDone;

    public void StartWork()
    {
    }

    void OnUnsubscribed()
    {
        //Place2
    }
}

class CatUser
{
    CatUser()
    {
        var cat = new Cat();
        cat.WorkDone += Cat_WorkDone;
        cat.WorkDone -= Cat_WorkDone; //<--- Place1
    }

    private void Cat_WorkDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an event is for a delegate what a property is for a backing field. You can write an event as

```
private EventHandler _workDone;
public event EventHandler WorkDone
{
    add
    {
        // Event subscriber subscribes
        _workDone += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        // Event subscriber unsubscribes
        _workDone -= value;
    }
}
```

Events are usually auto-implemented and automatically create the add- and remove-accessors in the background..

See also:

- [How to implement custom event accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)
- [.NET Matters / Event Accessors (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/november/net-matters-event-accessors) (shows an example of `Delegate.Remove`, see @madreflection's comment).
- [add (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add)
- [remove (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/remove)

Comment: I advise testing that something was actually removed in the `remove` accessor. `Delegate.Remove` (how `-=` is implemented for delegates) will return the same instance if `value` is not in the invocation list. If that's the case nothing was really unsubscribed.

Comment: I was talking about saving the value beforehand, doing the `-=` operation, and only calling `OnUnsubscribed` if they're not equal. I can edit that in, if you want.

Comment: @madreflection, thank you. I understood. It might not be necessary for what the OP has in mind. If his `+=` and `-=` are balanced, this will do the job. It also depends whether this is critical for what `OnUnsubscribed ` does. Likewise, locking will only be required if multithreading is used. Since we do not know the exact scenario, I prefer to keep it [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: I'm not even talking about locking here. I'm just talking about confirming that `value` was actually removed from the invocation list before calling `OnUnsubscribed`. If the right-hand side wasn't there to be removed, it doesn't make sense to notify unsubscription because nothing was actually unsubscribed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
 interface ICat
{
    void StartWork();
    event EventHandler WorkDone;
}
class Cat : ICat
{
    public event EventHandler WorkDone;

    public void StartWork()
    {
    }

    void OnUnsubscribed()
    {
        //Place2
    }

    internal void UnSubscribe(System.EventHandler cat_WorkDone)
    {
        this.WorkDone -= cat_WorkDone;
        OnUnsubscribed();
    }
}

class CatUser
{
    CatUser()
    {
        var cat = new Cat();
        cat.WorkDone += Cat_WorkDone;
        cat.UnSubscribe(Cat_WorkDone);
    }

    private void Cat_WorkDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```